# Unable to play Multiplayer in Battlefield 3 (missing dlcs) PS3

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3

I recently purchased Battlefield 3 for PS3, and I tried playing multiplayer yesterday. I entered the online pass, but when I try to find a server, every server visible to me has an alert symbol with this message `you are missing one or more dlcs played on this server`.

I'm not sure what's going on, do I need to buy an expansion pack, or download the maps, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure that this message appears because you are trying to connect to a server that uses one or more expansion packs. Try searching for a different server without any expansion packs.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. So is there a filter to search for server without expansion packs? sorry, I'm not on my PS3 now, so I can't check it out

Comment: Also, I don't need to have a premium account to play multiplayer right?

Comment: @Chaos to be honest, I've never played BF3 on a PS3(except for a couple of matches during beta), but it is certainly possible on a PC version. And no, Premium will only give you all the expansions and a few extra weapons. But you can still enjoy multiplayer with a normal version of BF3